# A similarity problem over matrices over Gaussian integers

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, matrices

Let $R =  \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$ and 
$$\Omega = \{X \in GL_4(R) : X \overline X = I_4 \text{ or } -I_4 \},$$
where $\overline  X$ is the complex conjugate matrix of $X$.

Two matrices $A, B \in \Omega $ are defined to be similar if 
$$B=U^{-1} A \overline U$$
for some $U \in GL_4(R)$.

Are the similarity classes of matrices in $\Omega$ classified?